# How to check for a question mark in PHP string using regex?

Tags: php, regex, string, url

I have a string returning a URL and need to figure out how to use `if` and regex to do something whenever the returned URL contains a question mark.

So when $url is `http://somedomain.com/?p=34325&blahblahblah`

IF the $url contains "`?p=`" (and discarding everything else) then exit, otherwise do something

Any help?
Many thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need a regex to match a simple string:

```
if (strpos($url, '?p=') !== false) {
   exit;
}
//do something
```

If you *really* wanted to use a regex:

```
if (preg_match('/\?p=/', $url)) {
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use regex for this. You do not need the power of regular pattern matching. Just use [strstr](http://php.net/strstr):

```
if(strstr($url, 'p=?')){
    exit;
}

// Do other stuff
```

Comment: Ok. Worked a treat. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: @WendiT It's an X/Y question. I answered "How to check for a question mark in PHP string?", because the best answer to "How to check for a question mark in PHP string using regex?" is simply "Don't". It is incorrect to use a regular expression for such a task in PHP.

Comment: ok clear. Do I need to use preg_match for multiple needles 5-6 needles) or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

`if (preg_match("/(\?p=)/", $url)) {`